# How is it possible that my SQLCommand + ExecuteScalar/ExecuteReader can return a result from another call?

Tags: sql, multithreading, sql-server-2008

I have 2 pieces of code which seem to be experiencing what can only be described as multi-threading issues.

I do not believe I have written any multi-threading code, but my code is running within the context of a webserver and hence the multi-threading is essentially part of the eco system.

The Code is SQL based, using ADO.Net.

(Note: I appreciate the potential for SQL injection attacks, but for now let us assume that this is dealt with because the SQL for these SQL commands cannot be directly influenced by user input)

**GetField** takes a SQLConnection and some SQL.

- It assumes that the SQL is structured as "Select **top 1 SomeField** from SomeTable".
- It creates a SQLCommand around this SQL
- It executes the command's ExecuteScalar function.
- It returns the value provided by ExecuteScalar

**GetRecord** similarly takes a SQLConnection and some SQL.

- It assumes that the SQL is structured as "Select **SomeFields** from SomeTable".
- It executes the command's ExecuteReader function.
- It parses the result provided by ExecuteReader into a known structure
- It returns the known structure

**The problem** I'm having is that occasionally the ExecuteReader function in GetRecord appears to be retrieving the result one would expect from GetField

This then falls over trying to parse the data into the known structure.

I cannot reproduce this reliably and so I'm asking for help.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

FWIW my back end SQL is SQL2008

**Update:** FWIW, the objects which own these methods, have their own connection field which is initialized to a new SQLConnection object which itself is fed a connection string from a central location.

**Update**: Here is an example of the sort of DA object I'm talking about.

---

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Module SomeModule
    Public Function GlobalConnection() As SqlConnection
        Return New SqlConnection(GetSQLStringFromConfig())
    End Function
End Module
Public Class ExampleDA
    Protected Con As SqlConnection
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Con = GlobalConnection()
    End Sub
    Public Function GetRecord(ByVal SQL As String) As String()
        Dim Close As Boolean = EnsureConnectionOpen(Con)
        Dim dc As New SqlCommand(SQL, Con)
        Try
            Dim DcExecuteReader As SqlDataReader
            If Close Then
                DcExecuteReader = dc.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Else
                DcExecuteReader = dc.ExecuteReader()
            End If
            ' ToStringArray doesn't exist but it gets the general point across.
            Return DcExecuteReader.ToStringArray() 
        Catch ex As SqlException
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function GetField(ByVal SQL As String, ByVal DefaultValue As Object) As Object
        Dim Close As Boolean = EnsureConnectionOpen(Con)
        Dim dc As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SQL, Con)
        Dim Result As Object = GetField(dc, DefaultValue)
        If Close Then Con.Close()
        Return Result
    End Function

    Private Function GetField(ByVal Command As SqlCommand, Optional ByVal DefaultValue As Object = Nothing) As Object
        Try
            Dim ReturnValue As Object
            Dim Close As Boolean = EnsureConnectionOpen(Command.Connection)
            ReturnValue = Command.ExecuteScalar()
            If ReturnValue Is Nothing Then
                ReturnValue = DefaultValue
            End If
            If Close Then
                Command.Connection.Close()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(ReturnValue) Then
                Return DefaultValue
            Else
                Return ReturnValue
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
    Private Function EnsureConnectionOpen(ByRef Con As SqlConnection) As Boolean
        If Con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            Con.Open()
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

---

Answer (score 1):

How are you handling connections the database?

One database connections = one process for SQL and these are not shared in anyway. To get "mixed" results will require that your are overwriting some context of a connection that is shared.

In other words, [SQLConnection is not thread safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx)

Comment: I'm newing up a SQLConnection object within the constructor of my DA object (example now edited into the question) and then sharing it around the methods that might need it internally within that class.

Answer (score 0):

How is the connection stored/shared between the functions?

Are you running under MARS? If not, try enabling it in your connection string (MultipleActiveResultSets=True).

Note that IIS may/will switch the execution context from one thread to another at its own will during execution. As such, any shared connection will eventually be shared between two threads and may fail. The use of MARS and/or explicitly new'ed connections should alleviate this.

Comment: If you run into MARS issues, I always had the issue that one execute failed with an exception since there was already a result set already open for this connection - I do not remember having mix-up issues. I encounter this form time to time since I do have the habit of typing my connection strings and sometimes missign the MARS clause...

Comment: I'm assuming that IIS switching something on me is what's responsible for this. but I was hoping to force something which would mean that this didn't matter.

I'm not using MARS at the moment, but it sounds interesting. But it begs the question, what did WebDevs do before MARS?

Comment: They did just as you should still do today - never share a SqlConnection or DataContext. Each time you use it, new one up and open the connection. Thanks to connection pooling that's no longer the issue it used to be back in the days. I ran int a similar issue that was caused by IIS thread switching as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208533/indexoutofrangeexception-on-queryable-single

Comment: Yeah I can totally see how sharing connections between threads is bad. 

As indicated in other answers, I'm pretty sure I'm newing up a SQLConnection for each batch of operations, and only from within a single master object which only lasts for the duration of a request at most.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I created a new DataContext and stored it in Context.Items - one per request and I'd never use it from multiple requests. Except I had weird errors that could only be explained by multiple threads accessing it at the same time. Later debugging revealed that IIS does indeed shift threads around. While it still shouldn't matter as long as two shifted threads don't use the object at the same time, completely avoiding the request-based connectioned solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one connection for one thing at one time, otherwise you may end up with unwanted results. Suppose someone opens a transaction on the connection without the other func knowing about?

You should always call GetConnection, since the backend does connection-pooling anyways. So performance-wise, it will most likely not matter.

hth

Mario

Comment: Ok that sounds like a very reasonable explanation. 

I was under the impression that as long as I created a new SQLConnection object (albeit with the same ConnectionString) that this would be a safe way to proceed.

Where might I find this GetConnection method?

Comment: That actually should be sufficient. I always use 'SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( connectionString ); connection.Open();' and never had any issues with a mix-up

Comment: can you post some code of the function and the use of the functions?

Comment: Ok I've added an example DA (DataAccess) class

Answer (score 0):

OK, that's asking for trouble! Rewrite your GetXXX methods along these lines (sorry for C# syntax but I am not familiar with VB ;-) )

```
GetField( string sqlCommand )
{
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( connectionString );
   conn.Open();

   try
   {
       using ( SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
       {
           cmd.CommandText = cmd;

           cmd.ExecuteScalar();


           //here be your code..

       }

   }
   finally
   { conn.Close();
   }
}
```

Do not store connections, do not do anything fency with them. Open and close as needed, the library does a command pooling behind the scenes!

hth

Mario

Comment: I did consider that. 

IIRC the reason we didn't was that we wanted to allow for the possibility of using transactions. ie we needed to have a higher layer decide it wanted to chain several commands into a single transaction. We would create a connection (ammend it to have a transaction) and then pass it around to 2 or 3 methods to perform writes with.

If anything failed along the way a rollback would undo each item which had been part of the transaction.

Comment: but then create the connection just where you would create the transaction and pass the connection around - because in my experience a transaction should be as short as possible and always follows a certain path, usually encapsulating some function calls at the same level. I also have a class that wraps DB-access and I do have a class encapsulating a connection, there you can specify whether the connection has a transaction or not.

Comment: ok sure, but aren't I already doing that. 
The connection is created in the constructor of my object. This object cannot be reached by any other thread (unless you know something I don't) and lasts only the life of the current WebRequest at most. 

Your advise sounds perfectly reasonable, but I just can't see how it conflicts with what I'm already doing :(

Comment: But aren't you reusing the GlobalConnection() ? ( I do not have much time to go deeply through your code now, I will do so in some hours whenn it's nite here..)

Comment: Ah I see the confusion. GlobalConnection is a badly named function (included in the code above). It returns a new instance of SQLConnection which wraps a connection string which is drawn from a config file. I guess it should have been called CreateConnectionFromGlobalConnectionString

Comment: FWIW I really appreciate all your help in this. Always helps to have someone else address a problem.

Comment: Sorry for just nosing around. I had now some time to look at the code and some questions pop up: It seems that you always close the connection in every call (ensure returns true)? A second question would be what the lifetime of the DA object is. One session or per application? Sorry for not being of real help...

Comment: FWIW this is rather old code, with precious little commenting. Technically it only closes the connection on the close of the function, if it had to open it at the start. This allowed for the possibility to have another method (in the DA object) which would create a new connection open it and then pass make several calls to existing methods which would not shut the connection on account of it being open when it was first encountered.

Comment: We would of course have to close it manually ourselves, but it gave us room to manoeuvre in. As for the length of the life of the DA object... typically they are around for less than the life of the Request. Typically created on page load and used throughout.

Comment: Having said that. I think there are some functions on shared items in session (Yeah I know. Not good, and perhaps part of the problem) which new up some DA objects, but they should be scoped to those functions and die as said functions are left.

Comment: I see... but from the code and what you tell me I do note see any obious issues, I share youre opinion that it should work. The only thing I do differently is that I keep the connection and the DA seperate. I create two swt of functions for eacht data request, one that gets passed the connection object, the other one that creates an intermediate object. This way you have more control of connection lifetime, possible transactions and the data getter implmentation itself.