# "Specified cast is not valid" error when saving LINQ-To-SQL entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

App Details:
C#, ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server 2008 ( Same version & SP level), Linq-To-SQL ORM

I'm trying to diagnose an exception I'm receiving:

> "Specified cast is not valid."
>   at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.SingleKeyManage`2.TryCreateKeyFromValues(Object[] values, V& v)
>   at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.Find(Object[] keyValues)
>   at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.Find(MetaType type, Object[] keyValues)
>   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(MetaType type, Object[] keyValues)
>   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.GetOtherItem(MetaAssociation assoc, Object instance)
>   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.BuildEdgeMaps()
>   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
>   at Repository.Save()
>   at etc....

The problem is that this is occurring only on our servers, not on our local development boxes.  I've tracked it down to a single property we're modifying:

```
event.SalesForceId = "701Q0000000AOTIIA4";
```

If I comment out that line, everything works fine.

I've tried:

1 ) waxing all of the code on the server and redeploying. Same issue.
2 ) Pulling down a copy of the server DB and trying it locally.  Works fine.
3 ) Trying another IIS environment we have setup on the same box.  Same issue.
4 ) Physically comparing ( using AdeptSQL ) both local and remote schemas.  No differences.
5 ) Verifying the datatypes of both columns ( local and remote ) are the same.  Also, this column is a FK to another table.  I verified that both are of the same data type, down to the collation.

The server is Windows Server 2008 and the local box is Windows 7 x64. Both have all important updates setup.

The only thing I can think of is perhaps since the database and web server are on different boxes that could be an issue?  Otherwise, I'm completely stumped.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of `V` in that last call? Use the debugger to see that.

Comment: This is .net 3.5, not 4, with all service packs applied.  Also, I can't use the debugger to step through it because it's on the server.  Remote debugging is also not an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a well-known bug in LINQ to SQL.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=351358

There is a hotfix for the issue.

http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=963657&kbln=en-us

Comment: I downloaded 963657 and tried to install it but it is giving me following error: None of the products that are addressed by this software update are installed on this computer. Click Cancel to exit setup. This is because 963657 is for framework 3.5 SP1 but I am having framework 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

If that key exists in a defined relationship *and* the object is already created then the LINQ-provided relationship path (`obj.Foo = new Foo { ... }`) *must* be used. (I would use the provided relationships even for new objects). Failure to do so will result -- speaking from experience -- in "random" errors like that.

Another issue that can cause that (or a very similar error) is *reversed relationship columns*, for compound relationships. However, if the generated code is the same and the DB is the same (for real, on both accounts) then I suspect the first reason is the culprit.

Happy SQL-to-LINQ pothole jumping.

Comment: Interesting, but I have usually had the 'normal' `NullReferenceException` in those cases IIRC. If we can find out why it is failing to cast (to `string` I assume) it would be helpful.

Comment: @leppie I'd gladly give up my favorite sock if I could find a "cookbook" for dealing with LINQ errors :-/

Comment: +1 I want one too. Usually, if I can attach to the process and use a debugger, it is not too hard to find out what is going on internally (with a little help from Reflector of course), then trace back to the problem (looking at the state/locals in the managed stack).

Comment: the object does not exist yet.  "event" in the original code snippet is the referenced object in the FK.  So the referencing object will come at a later time.  Also, this is only happening in a specific environment, not everywhere.  That's why it's so puzzling.

Comment: @leppie: exactly.  I assumed at first there was some type mismatch in the db / dbml / generated .cs file.  But everything is a string.