# Invalid Cast Exception Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I wrote some payroll software for my company (approx. 250 employees) and when you load the software it will prompt you and say a new employee has been added to the database.  The prompt forces you to select what class they are (manager, sales, labor, etc).  This part of the program works for all users except two of the users that use the software.  These two users can cancel the prompt and continue using the software with no problems (and the part of the software that works for them uses the same database as the one the prompt uses, "AttendanceData").  Here is the error they get when they submit the "employee class" info:

> Specified cast is not valid.    at
>   System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.SingleKeyManager`2.TryCreateKeyFromValues(Object[]
>   values, V& v)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.Find(Object[]
>   keyValues)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.Find(MetaType
>   type, Object[] keyValues)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(MetaType type,
>   Object[] keyValues)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.GetOtherItem(MetaAssociation assoc,
>   Object instance)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.BuildEdgeMaps()    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode
>   failureMode)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()

Below I have provided the code that handles this prompt:

```
using (AttendanceDataContext AttendanceData = new AttendanceDataContext())
                {
                    var attEmpTbl = AttendanceData.EMPLOYEEs.Where(i => i.ACTIVESTATUS == 0 &&
                                                                   (i.WG2 == 1 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 14 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 16 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 18 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 20 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 21 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 23 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 25 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 27 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 29 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 30 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 32 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 35 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 38 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 40 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 49 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 51 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 54 ||
                                                                   i.WG2 == 59)).OrderBy(i => i.WG2);
                    List<int> commEmpFilekey = new List<int>();

                    using (CommissionsDataContext CommissionData = new CommissionsDataContext())
                    {
                        commEmpFilekey = CommissionData.EmployeeLists.Select(i => i.FileKey).ToList();
                    }
                    if (commEmpFilekey.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        int records = 0;
                        int record = 1;
                        foreach (var item in attEmpTbl)
                        {
                            if (!commEmpFilekey.Contains(item.FILEKEY.Value))
                            {
                                records++;
                            }
                        }
                        foreach (var item in attEmpTbl)
                        {

                            if (!commEmpFilekey.Contains(item.FILEKEY.Value))
                            {
                                string commID;
                                using (EmployeeEntry ee = new EmployeeEntry(item.FIRSTNAME, item.LASTNAME, item.BADGE.Value, record, records, item.WG2.Value))
                                {
                                    DialogResult result = ee.ShowDialog();
                                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                                    {
                                        using (CommissionsDataContext data = new CommissionsDataContext())
                                        {
                                            commID = ee.commID;
                                            EmployeeList employee = new EmployeeList { FileKey = item.FILEKEY.Value, Badge = item.BADGE.Value, CommID = commID };
                                            data.EmployeeLists.InsertOnSubmit(employee);
                                            data.SubmitChanges();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                record++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Again, this code works fine with all users EXCEPT our "payroll" and "hr" users.  Also, every user who uses the software, works off of our local terminal server, so it's not like those two users' local PCs don't have the right references...  I'm baffled by this...

Comment: Never liked nested using statements, let alone nesting datacontexts... that would worry me. Perhaps you could at least explicitly connect and disconnect them to prevent as much as possible (without a lot of coding) them being pooled. AttendanceData.Connection.Open() etc

Comment: I wonder - is the key on the EmployeeLists non-numeric? There was (is) a bug in L2S regarding this: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801364/specified-cast-is-not-valid-error-when-saving-linq-to-sql-entity

Comment: You should use `Contains` instead of that horrible `OR` sequence.

Comment: EmployeeLists.FileKey is an <int> value...

Comment: I wonder if I shouldn't try this:  `commEmpFileKey = CommissionData.EmployeeLists.Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Filekey).ToList();`

Comment: Please forgive my "taboo" coding (the horrible `OR` sequence).  I had two weeks to write this program and it's pretty big (about 4000 lines of code).  It handles 250 employees' payroll and commissions.