# update using linq - VS2008/C#

Tags: linq

This is my query:

```
var query = (from v in _dataContext.UserInterests
                             join u in _dataContext.Users on v.UserId equals u.UserId
                             where u.Email.Equals(EmailAddress)
                             select v);


foreach (UserInterest reg in query)
{
    reg.Promotion = "1234-24323-1212";
    //other properties

    _dataContext.SubmitChanges()
}
```

No error is evoked, however when I look at my DB record, no changes are made. EmailAddress will become a comma separated value and hence the foreach loop above

Why does the above not throw an error but fails to update the db record.

The error I get is that invalid cast error. Prompotion is a varchar type in sql

Stack Trace:

```
 at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.SingleKeyManager`2.TryCreateKeyFromValues(Object[] values, V& v)
   at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.Find(MetaType type, Object[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(MetaType type, Object[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.GetOtherItem(MetaAssociation assoc, Object instance)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.BuildEdgeMaps()
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query variable contains any UserInterest objects?  If not, it won't enter the for loop.

Comment: Tim: It does contain the object. It enters the loop but no change is observed in the DB for that email

Comment: When do you get the invalid cast error?

Comment: right after submitchanges is called

Comment: This is not an answer, but just a note: do you need SubmitChanges in the loop? Why not after it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a key field on the UserInterests object?
Also check these:

[Debugging LINQ to SQL SubmitChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86685/debugging-linq-to-sql-submitchanges)

http://forums.asp.net/p/1223080/2187580.aspx

Comment: +2 yes, missing or incorrect PK in the model is the most likely cause